# Scala, collapsing Option of an Option

Tags: scala, scala-option

Im wondering if there is a short hand for collapsing a map of an option. For example

```
def divideByThree(x:Int) = if (x == 0) None else Some(x/3)

val result = Some(6) map (divideByThree(_))
resut:Option[Option[Int]] = Some(Some(2))
```

To fix this I do

```
val result = Some(6) match {
   case Some(i) => divideByThree(i)
   case None    => None
}
```

Which seems a bit heavy going.  I could create an implicit function on Option say mapOption to deal with this, but am wondering if there is a nicer way I haven't thought of.

Comment: You're on your way to [rediscovering monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html)!  The ability to collapse nested structure/provide a `flatMap`/`mapOption`-like function is half of what makes up a monad, in addition to providing a way to embed values (here, `Some`) (and, in the latter case, a `map` operation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` like in:

```
def divideByThree(x:Int) = if (x == 0) None else Some(x/3)

val opx = None // Or: Some(10)
val mapped = opx.flatMap(divideByThree)

println(mapped)
```

Comment: Its all kinds of obvious once you see it.  
Its always a good reminder to think of Option as a list of (at most) one element.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

How about `flatMap()` ? It'll perform the `map` and then `flatten`

```
val result = Some(6) flatMap (divideByThree(_))
result: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala has kind of monadic syntax: *for comprehension*

```
val div = ( case x if x%3 == 0 => x/3} : PartialFunction[Int,Int] ).lift
val exp = (l : Option[Int]) => for {
             x <- l
             r <- div(x)
           } yield r
```

test it:

```
scala> exp(Some(3))
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> exp(Some(4))
res2: Option[Int] = None

scala> exp(None)
res3: Option[Int] = None
```